# jQuery search if found element child

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, controls, find

Hi my html looks like this:

```
<ul class="first">
  <li>
    <div class="tg-hey">hey</div>
    <div class="tg-hi">hi</div>
    <div class="tg-hoi">hoi</div>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="second">
  <li>
    <div class="tg-hey">hey</div>
    <div class="tg-hi">hi</div>
    <div class="tg-hoi">hoi</div>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="third">
  <li>
    <div class="tg-hey">hey</div>
    <div class="tg-hi">hi</div>
    <div class="tg-hoi">hoi</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

what i need is to find if (for example in `<ul class="second">`) the `<div class="tg-hey">` exist or not.

how can i check it?

Comment: If what exists?  A particular class?

Comment: yep sorry forgot to highlight as code, now you can see ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create the selector and check the length of the result (if it is 0 it will be false, otherwise it is true):

```
if ($('ul.second div.tg-hey').length) {
    alert("It exists");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SgnvH/

Answer (score 5):

```
if($(".second:has(.tg-hey)").length) {
    // do something
}
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/JkPNA/1/)

If you need to *do something* to the matching element(s), you don't really need to test first, since nothing will happen if there are no matches, so:

```
$(".second:has(.tg-hey)").hide();
```

is perfectly safe.

Another way is to use `.is` and `:has`:

```
if($(".second").is(":has(.tg-hey)")) {
    // do something
}
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/JkPNA/2/)

but I wouldn't do that since it just seems like too much jQuery for a fairly simple task.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".second").has(".tg-hey").length > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
if ($('ul.second div.tg-hey').length > 0)
  // exists
else
  // doesn't
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.className').length
```

if `$('.className').length == 0`, then the element does not exist.

**Edit:**

`$('.second').length` will tell you how many elements have the class "second".

`$('.second .tg-hey').length` will tell you how many elements have the class "tg-hey" inside the class "second".

This assumes that you are using jQuery!

Comment: Here is an example of my solution working, BTW.  Not sure why I got a down vote.

http://jsfiddle.net/mdw233/4WG4m/